# Use an entry input as a file name Python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, input, filenames

I need to create an excel file then name it using a `tkinter` textbox, in other words I need to store the `tkinter entry getvalue` into a variable then assign it as a name to the file that I'll create.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_entry_fields():
    print("Nom du rapport global: %s" % (e1.get()))

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="Nom du rapport global").grid(row=0)

e1 = tk.Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

tk.Button(master, 
          text='Quit', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=1, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)
tk.Button(master, 
          text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, 
                                                       column=0, 
                                                       sticky=tk.W, 
                                                       pady=4)
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(e1.get()+'.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Rapport global")
worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 25)
worksheet.set_column(1, 2, 25)
worksheet.write('F3', "Hello") 
worksheet.write('G3', "world") 
workbook.close()

tk.mainloop()
master.withdraw()
```

It creates an excel file, but with no name, I don't know how to retrieve the input entry and assign it as a file name

Comment: I think the problem is you create the excel sheet in the loop so as soon as the window opens it creates the excel sheet with the empty field. You can assign e1.get to a global variable and make the sheet outside the loop or you can make a save function tied to a save button for example

Comment: It creates an unnamed file because your script run all the way down "workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(e1.get()+'.xlsx')" and set the name to " " because your Entry field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have xlsxwriter but I assume that your

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(e1.get()+'.xlsx')
```

is executed before you set a value in the entry box.

One possible solution would be:

Get the entry value and store it in a variable. To do that I create another button
called **but_save**. This button calls the method **save_entry** which get the value of 
entry input and stores in a variable.

Run the script, type the desired name and press **Save** button.

Didn't store variable in a Microsoft Excel file format because I don't have this module
but for simplicity I store it in a text file. You should be able to store it as a xsl as well.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, Button

class Set_Name():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.init_widgets()

    def show_entry_fields(self):
        print("Nom du rapport global: %s" % (self.e1.get()))

    def init_widgets(self):

        self.lab_1 = Label(self.master, text="Nom du rapport global")
        self.lab_1.grid(row=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(self.master)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.but_quit = Button(self.master, text='Quit', command=self.master.quit)
        self.but_quit.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='W', pady=4)
        self.but_show = Button(self.master, text='Show', command=self.show_entry_fields)
        self.but_show.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W', pady=4)
        self.but_save = Button(self.master, text="Save", command=self.save_entry)
        self.but_save.grid(row=3, column=2)

    def save_entry(self):
        # I don't have xlsxwriter.
        file_name = self.e1.get()   # get the string from Entry
        with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write("Hello World!") # write whatever you want

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Set_Name(root)
    root.mainloop()
```